# NMAP Scan- Results Differ

Tags: nmap, ip

I'm trying to determine a server IP address via ping and open ports/services by running an NMAP scan.

At work, when I ping my website/server, I get a response from `172.16.XX.X`.

If I run an NMAP scan, it brings a back a list of open ports/services. As expected.

However, from my home computer, when a ping is sent, I get a response from a completely different address `69.XXX.XXX.XX`

If I run an NMAP scan on this address, it only brings back primary and secondary mail servers. `mail.xxx.ca` and `mail2.xxx.ca`.

**Some things to note:**

At work (scenario one), I am behind a firewall.

I know there is an FTP service running on this server/website.

This site requires HTTPS, and HTTP request are redirected to HTTPS.

Does anyone know why these would be so different?

Comment: The second octet of the 172.x.x.x address would be helpful.  Sounds like it might be an internal address (172.[16-31].x.x) which could be the firewall or some network security device/proxy at your work network.

Comment: @armani see edit

Comment: Please review material regarding private and public IP blocks. Private IP blocks cannot be routed over the Internet and are NAT'ed.

Answer (score 3):

172.16.x.x is a reserved LAN IP, meaning your workplace has likely a proxy for traffic outbound to the Internet that must be intercepting your nmap scan.  This is why you are getting a different IP and different results when scanning from work versus scanning from home.

Comment: Not necessarily a proxy, but simply NAT.